# React checkbox group validation in form (no libraries)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, validation, conditional-statements

I am trying to add a conditional statement so that an error message will show if the checkboxes aren't checked in my form. I have the "validate" function that does this for my other required values but am having a hard time working with checkboxes.

Can someone show me how to do this without using any additional libraries?

Many thanks!

Main Form Component:
https://gist.github.com/kpermenter/62511ac6887e7c8f485e307ec990ccb0

Comment: Please create a [mre] (emphasis on minimal) and put it inside the question.

Comment: I am just trying to come up with a conditional statement to place an error message on any checkbox not checked. I have a simple onChange handler but am stuck as to where to go from there:   handleCheckGroupElemenet = (event) => {
    let fruites = this.state.fruites
    fruites.forEach(fruite => {
       if (fruite.value === event.target.value)
          fruite.isChecked =  event.target.checked
    })
    this.setState({fruites: fruites})
  }

Comment: You're already mapping over `this.state.fruites` to display them; adding an error is basically just `{!fruite.isChecked && <p>Error here</p>}`. You should also turn them into controlled inputs, meaning you need to add `checked={fruite.isChecked}` to the checkbox.

Comment: Side note: line 61 `this.setState({ errors: {} });` will not work like you think it does; changes to state are asynchronous and this line has zero effect.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. Can you show me how you would implement the function in order to catch an error for the checkboxes? I am new to React and can't seem to figure out how to put it all together. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: It looks like all you need is `if (this.state.fruites.some(fruite => !fruite.isChecked)) errors.fruites = "Please check all fruit";` It doesn't seem to be a React thing; isn't counting unchecked fruit all you need to do, basic array stuff?